# How do I implement a ReactJS app into my Flask app?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I have a ReactJS frontend with multiple routes. e.g.: `/`, `/example1`, `example1/example2/example3/example4`.

I have used the react-build script to make production build of the ReactJS app. Now I'm trying to incorporate the ReactJS app with the Flask app.

This is what I have so far on my Flask routes:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="./build", static_url_path="")
CORS(app)
app.secret_key = secret_key


@app.route("/", defaults={"path": ""})
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def serve(path):
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
```

This works, but not for all routes. For example, `/example1` and `/example1/example2` work. But `/example1/example2/example3` doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT:
It turns out that `/example1/example2` does not work, meaning that the issue is to do with custom routes, which aren't predefined. All routes which I have specifically defined work, but the dynamically made ones don't.

Comment: Don't you want to do this: `return app.send_static_file(path)`?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work do you mean it returns a 404? If so I think Flask is unable to find the static file `index.html`, is the `./build` location correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-deploy-a-react-router-flask-application - this might help you for now, the tutorial has modified the 404 exception handler (Not really an elegant solution but works).

```py
@app.errorhandler(404)
    def not_found(e):
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

Comment: this worked! Obviously this isn't ideal, but it works. Thank you!